# C++ - Visual Studio - LINK : fatal error C1047: The object or library file was created with an older compiler than other objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, object, linker, libraries

I'm trying to build a project in Visual Studio 2015 but getting the following error from Visual Studio:

```
LINK : fatal error C1047: The object or library file '..\..\SOIL\Release\SOIL.lib' was 
created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
```

Now I've seen other questions on similar issues, and solutions tend to be along the lines of

> "Rebuild your libraries"

owtte. I have tried rebuilding the entire soloution using:
[image]

I have also tried cleaning the solution using:
[image]

After doing both these things the same error occurs.

I am posting this as a separate question because it seems to me that my problem could actually be different than theirs.

I do not know how nor whether I can just build old objects and/or libraries and I cannot find any information on this topic. Any insight on this would be greatly useful to me.

Thank you :)

Comment: Is SOIL.lib part of your project or an external library?

Comment: It is not then. You most likely need to get a version of SOIL.lib which was also compiled with VS2015

Comment: Hang on, you are building a solution and don't know which code is yours, and which code isn't yours? That's not the best start. Anyway, see [Fatal Error C1047](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173554.aspx) for additional information. In short: If you are compiling the object code, rebuild the solution. If you aren't compiling the object code, disable /LTCG for that object file.

Comment: It is saying `'..\..\SOIL\Release\SOIL.lib'` was created with some other compiler. Where did you get this SOIL.lib from?

Comment: You need `SOIL.lib` that's either compiled with the compiler you are using, or without the `/LTCG` compiler option. We cannot help you find out, what `SOIL.lib` is, or who the vendor/author is. This is something you have to know (or find out, if you don't).